# The benefit of static array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know what is the difference between static array like this below:

```
static $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
```

and this array :

```
$lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
```

Comment: It depends on the context. In the global namespace? In a function/method? As a class property?

Answer (score 2):

If a attribute is static it can be accessed without creating an instance of this class.

```
//static
class MyClass(){
        static $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
}
var_dump (MyClass::$lang)

//public
class MyClass(){
        public $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
}
$obj = new MyClass();
var_dump($obj->lang);
```

Static properties are accessed using the Scope Resolution Operator (`::`) and cannot be accessed through the object operator (`->`).

A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

```
function myFunction()
{
    $nonStatic = 0;
    echo $nonStatic;
    $nonStatic++;
}

myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 0
myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 0
myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 0
myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 0
```

The function test always returns Zero as the `$nonStatic` variable lose its value.

While in this function:

```
function myFunction()
{
    static $staticVar = 0;
    echo $staticVar;
    $staticVar++;
}

myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 0
myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 1
myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 2
myFunction(); // OUTPUT: 3
```

Because the `$staticVar` variable is static, so it retain its value.

The same applies to your array

```
function test()
{
    static $lang = array(
        'message' => 'Welcome ',
        'admin' => 'administrator'
    );

    var_dump($lang);
    $lang['message'] = 'new message ';
}

test(); // OUTPUT: array(2) { ["message"]=> string(6) "Welcome" ["admin"]=> string(9) "administrator" }
test(); // OUTPUT: array(2) { ["message"]=> string(6) "new message" ["admin"]=> string(9) "administrator" }
```

To access a static variable or method from inside the class you can use the `self` keyword. To access a static variable or calling a method from a class that is extended by the class containing the static variable you can use the `parent` keyword

```
class MyClass{
        static $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
        static function myFunction(){
            return self::$lang;
        }
}

class ScndClass extends MyClass{
    public function callStaticFunction(){
        var_dump(parent::$lang);
        return parent::$myFunction();
    }
}
$obj = new ScndClass();
echo $obj->callStaticFunction();
```

Read [more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) about the `static` Keyword.

Comment: `class myClass(){...}` should be `class myClass{...}` - i.e. drop the parentheses `()`. Also, most often class names are in PascalCase, e.g. `MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

Please review this
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties

> A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

So in the following example:

```
    function test()
    {
        $a = 0;
        echo $a;
        $a++;
    }
    
    test(); // OUTPUT: 0
    test(); // OUTPUT: 0
    test(); // OUTPUT: 0
    test(); // OUTPUT: 0
```

The function test always returns Zero as the `$a` variable lose its value.

While in this function:

```
    function test()
    {
        static $a = 0;
        echo $a;
        $a++;
    }
    
    test(); // OUTPUT: 0
    test(); // OUTPUT: 1
    test(); // OUTPUT: 2
    test(); // OUTPUT: 3
```

Because the `$a` variable is static, so it retain its value.

Also in array,

```
    function test()
    {
        static $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
    
        var_dump($lang);
        $lang['message'] = 'Hello ';
    }
    
    test(); // OUTPUT: array(2) { ["message"]=> string(6) "Welcome" ["admin"]=> string(9) "administrator" }
    test(); // OUTPUT: array(2) { ["message"]=> string(6) "Hello" ["admin"]=> string(9) "administrator" }
```

In the previous example, the first run will output "Welcome administartor", while the second run will output "Hello administrator".

Also,

> Static variables can be assigned values which are the result of constant expressions, but dynamic expressions, such as function calls, will cause a parse error.

so the following example will cause error

```php
$name = "Omar";
static $lang = array(
    'message' => 'Welcome ',
    'admin' => 'administrator' . $name,
);
var_dump($lang); // Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

While the following code is valid one:

```php
$name = "Omar";
$lang = array(
    'message' => 'Welcome ',
    'admin' => 'administrator' . $name,
);
var_dump($lang); // OUTPUT: array(2) { ["message"]=> string(9) "Welcome " ["admin"]=> string(12) "administratorOmar" }
```

Also note this:

> Static properties are accessed using the Scope Resolution Operator (::) and cannot be accessed through the object operator (->).

> It's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value cannot be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

So the following example is valid

```
    class Foo
    {
        static $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
    }
    var_dump(Foo::$lang); // array(2) { ["message"]=> string(9) "Welcome " ["admin"]=> string(9) "administrator" }
```

While the following example will throw fatal error

```
    class Foo
    {
        public $lang = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome ',
            'admin' => 'administrator'
        );
    }
    var_dump(Foo::$lang); // Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property Foo::$lang
```